# sdl2 (pysdl2) without x11 using directFB or OpenGL ES

Tags: python, x11, sdl-2, directfb, pysdl2

I am working on Debian based embedded systems that avoids the overhead of windowing systems by running graphics directly to the screen using FBCON (similar to DirectFB). This is common with Raspberry Pi screens and there are plenty of resources to do this with pygame 1.9.1 (SDL1.2 based) and FBCON. Python 2.7 and pygames 1.9.1 running with FBCON is my currently working arrangement.

I want to move to Python 3 and the improved SDL2 library (pygames updates are very slow), but I need to retain the lower level graphics capability. I see little documentation of the level of support besides a couple mentions of DirectFB capability.

I am not using Raspberry Pi, so specific solutions to the Pi will be less helpful for me.

Before going to deep, I wanted to see if anybody else has experience with this.

- Has anybody successfully run pysdl2 or just sdl2 without x11?
- Was there any issues or changes besides the flag for the DirectFB driver?
- Has anybody tried this with the alpha pygames 1.9.2?

Besides being helpful for myself I think this would be great for the community. I see other asking similar questions but with minimal or no useful answers.

Thanks for the time

References:

[pysdl2](https://bitbucket.org/marcusva/py-sdl2)

[libsdl](https://www.libsdl.org/index.php)